# How to create a sub folder within a Views folder in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm brand new to MVC3.  I am having a hard time trying to add a subfolder to the Controller.  This is what I have *http://www.site.com/folder/filename* and what I'm trying to do is this *http://www.site.com/folder/subfolder/filename*.  Is this possible in MVC3?  How do I update the Controller to handle subfolders? or Global.asax if needed?

Any help that you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are talking about routes?

Comment: MVC does not serve files by their physical location.

Comment: I know MVC does not serve them like that.  But is there anyway that I could have subfolders if needed?

Comment: can it be done thru routes?

Comment: You can have as many subfolders as you like in your project. In order for the URL to appear that way, you have to properly set up routes.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how this would be done thru routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Accessing http://example.org/first/second/third will use the `TopSecret` controller and its `Index` action to serve the view.
- Accessing http://example.org/home will use the `Home` controller and its default action, `Index`.
- Accessing http://example.org/not/correct will give you an error if the `Not` controller or its action `correct` does not exist, because MVC will look for it based on a match with the latter route mapping.

  ```
  routes.MapRoute(
      name: null,
      url: "first/second/third/", 
      defaults: new { controller = "TopSecret", action = "Index" },
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
  );
  ```

Also notice that the order in which you map routes is important.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Then, what should I put in controller TopSecret?  what should the ActionResult be?

Comment: And what if there are more pages in that subfolder, how does the route handle all pages?

Comment: The `Index` action can return a View (it's a descendant of ActionResult, more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult(v=vs.108).aspx).

Comment: Note that the actual files are not located in the path specified by the URL used. You can tailor the URL any way you like, regardless of your project structure.

Comment: It helps me understand, but I am still confused about the controller, how do I set the actionResult for such a link in the controller?  Please explain.

Comment: @JohnQ In your contollers, you don't care about URLs. Just return a View in the `Index` method. The mapped route will take care if the rest -- invoke `Index` in `TopSecret` This is very basic MVC stuff, I suggest you look for some tutorials on the structure of MVC.

Comment: I guess so.  Thanks, you were very helpful